# Why does reading from a symlink to network location cause local disk activity?

Tags: symlink, monitoring, disk

I am running RHEL 6.4 and have a symbolic link in my home directory to a large file stored elsewhere on a network. My home directory is a network location as well. I've noticed that when I run a Python script (also on a remote machine) that reads and does some processing on the large file, System Monitor 2.28.0 shows a large jump in local disk activity, shown in orange here:

[image]

Since the symlink, the file, the script being executed, and even the execution itself are all occurring on remote machines, why is my local disk activity increasing?

I have seen [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/51913/93816) elsewhere on this site, and it suggests that the Kernel should resolve the real path name once and then subsequent reads from the file should go to that location, but that doesn't seem to be what is happening here.

Comment: Shouldn't the execution take place at your local system, i.e, any CPU or RAM requirement would be fulfilled by your local system, so correspondingly any files it needs would be cached here as well?

Comment: @muru Nope. Execution is on a server as well. Local CPU and memory usage are unaffected as shown in the first two boxes, respectively (blue and green).

Comment: I would say what you're saying is impossible, unless either a) you're executing the script remotely using SSH or the like, or b) your script does all it's work remotely, using RPC, etc.)

Comment: @muru I just did a test, and when I explicitly use ssh to connect to a remote system and run the script there, the disk activity does *not* increase anymore. I'm not sure what to make of that difference though. I normally run my script on one of my workplace's grid machines, and System Monitor doesn't report any increase in local CPU or memory usage, but disk activity does increase with this method.